# Уведомляем в том, или о том?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "Уведомляем Вас в том" или "Уведомляем Вас о том"? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ:

УВЕДОМИТЬ кого-что. Офиц.Сообщить, известить о чём-л. Министерство связи уведомило население о начале подписки. Надо заблаговременно у. сотрудников о ликвидации нашего предприятия.

Таким образом, правильно будет: "Уведомляем Вас о том..."